# converting base64 to binary before uploading (advice)

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, base64, binaryfiles

Looking for advice for uploading files to the server.

We are currently uploading images to the server with `javascript` as `base64 encoded` strings and using the `base64` string as the sources of an HTML img tag for previewing purposes. The url, after the `base64` is saved on the server, is used elsewhere.

The `base64 encoded` strings are send to the server inside a `JSON` object and converted to files on the server side.

How efficient will it be if we convert the `base64` to `binary` before sending it to the server? If read that `binary` will be 33% smaller in size. And is it possible to save the `binary` strings inside the `JSON` object?

Comment: Well it really depends on what you mean. If you are planning to transfer binary as ASCII/UTF-8, it will be very unoptimized, as each character (0/1) will be a byte each. Whereas a byte of Base64 carries a lot more data.

Comment: @dnorhoj well the general question is how to upload the image as efficient as possible to the server. I read the image contents from a HTML file input element as base64 and trying to figure out if I need to convert it to binary first before uploading to the server.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean exactly by "converting" it to binary? If it's by rendering the content as one's and zero's, it will only increase the size dramatically, while base64 is really good for http safe transfer of binary files.